# Using google APIs with vue js

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, google-api

I wanted to know if it was possible to use google apis with service account on a Vuejs project.
Since this library https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client  isn't working with vue 2.x.

How can I generate credentials to make http request to the google API ?

Some API's require JWT will this be enough as credential ?

In my case, I want to use analytics and google search console API only but I can't manage to find how to perform request on these api.

Thanks a lot for any help or reply.

Comment: *isn't working with vue 2.x* - what did make you think so? The lib is framework independent. Since it doesn't affect the view, it doesn't matter if you use it with Vue, jQuery or anything else. What did you try and what were the problems?

Comment: importing the lib always returns an error, it seems like is it not compatible with webpack.

Comment: The example shows that it isn't supposed to be imported, https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/samples.md . It's hosted by Google.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @EstusFlask, i'll give it a try soon

Answer (score 0):

`Service account` authentication is more suited on the backend since you don't want to include your secret key in a frontend project.

In a frontend project, depending on which API you want to use and which data you want to access, there are two options:

- use an `API key` to authenticate your requests, although this is not always possible for all APIs. Usually, if you have to access user data you would rather implement `OAuth2` authentication.
- `OAuth2 authentication`. Use the Google Javascript client library to authenticate the user and let the user grant your application permissions to access the data you want to.

To use the `Javascript Client Libraries` in your Vuejs 2.x project you could use this plugin (available on npmjs.org) [vue-googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-googleapis)

It is as simple as doing:

```js
Vue.use(GoogleAPIs, {
  clientId: '<CLIENT_ID>.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  discoveryDocs: ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest'],
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
})
```

and you will have all the Google APIs at your disposal in the `Vue` instance (i.e. everywhere in your codebase)

Of course you will have to adjust the configuration with the `scope` and `discoveryDocs` based on what API you need to use and which access level you need.

This repo has few examples on how to use the plugin for different tasks in your Vuejs project

[vue-gogleapis-examples](https://github.com/ql4b/vue-googleapis-examples)